# Commutation of covariant derivatives

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tangent-spaces

Let $u: V \rightarrow M$, where $(V,g)$ is a Lorentzian manifold and $(M,h)$ is a Riemannian manifold. Also $V=S \times R$, where $S$ is an $n$-dimensional orientable smooth manifold.
Now i $\partial_i u^A$ and $\partial_t u^A$ are mappings from $S \times R$ into $T^∗ V\otimes TM$.

Now in a paper, there is an expression for

$D_i \nabla^{\lambda} \nabla_{\lambda} u^A$

I don't understand what $\nabla^{\lambda} \nabla_{\lambda}$ means, I've never seen the term $\nabla^{\lambda}$ before.

Comment: It's $g^{\lambda \mu} \nabla_{\mu} \nabla_{\lambda}$.

Comment: Thank you! Just to be sure: you are using the Einstein summ. convention?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes.

Comment: Sorry, another question, the sum goes over both indices?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Another question on that: If we sum over both indices, does that mean that the expression is just a function?

Comment: Which expression?

Comment: $\nabla^{\lambda} \nabla_{\lambda} u^A$

Comment: $\nabla^{\lambda}\nabla_{\lambda}u^{A}$ for fixed $u^{A}$ is a real-valued local function. But $\nabla^{\lambda}\nabla_{\lambda}$ is a function sending smooth function to smooth function.

Comment: I understand, thank you again!